# Acumatica Authorization Flow

Tags: .net, vb.net, oauth-2.0, acumatica

I am trying to connect to Acumatica with the [Authorization Flow](https://help.acumatica.com/%28W%281%29%29/Main.aspx?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ff780860-09c2-46c9-bdd7-c6c3b1fc442c) instead of the [Resource Owner Password Flow](https://help.acumatica.com/%28W%281%29%29/Main.aspx?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=2930d2f7-e081-4d0e-8879-93907ce82607), which is the only flow I have been able to find [examples](https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/integration/i210-contract-based-web-services/) for. I have tried various subsets of the "URL of the Acumatica ERP instance to which the client application is going to connect" for the `<Acumatica ERP instance URL>` cited in the Authorization Flow link I posted above as a Service Reference, but none of them seem to get me any endpoints that have anything I could pass a token to (indeed, they all just fail altogether, with variations on a reference that could not be resolved or access not allowed). For reference, the complete URL is https://try.acumatica.com/isv/entity/Default/6.00.001?wsdl&company=(My Company's Name). This works to get the Password Flow, but not the Authorization Flow.

How do I actually implement the Authorization Flow?

Answer (score 0):

The whole flows are actually described by the link you've already seen yourself: https://help.acumatica.com/Main.aspx?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=a8f71c44-9f5c-4af8-9d47-bc815c8a58e7

The url you're looking for is `https://try.acumatica.com/isv/identity/`, which gives you `https://try.acumatica.com/isv/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration` as OIDC Discovery endpoint, which gives you `https://try.acumatica.com/isv/identity/connect/authorize` as authorization endpoint and `https://try.acumatica.com/isv/identity/connect/token` as token endpoint.

Comment: That's the one I was getting the error `Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://try.acumatica.com/isv/identity/'. The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.` from when I tried adding a service reference to it. Adding the various bits after `/identity/` got assorted variations on the same theme.

Comment: Okay, I'm testing out the assumption that this is because I didn't specify the URL Parameters.

Comment: Nope, adding the URL Parameters still gives the same error.

Comment: That gives the same error. Is there some other way I should be doing this than a Service Reference?

Comment: If you are talking about Visual Studio's Add Service Reference dialog, then it has nothing to do with OAuth/OIDC at all. You should use some authorization client (like [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2)) to work with tokens, and then pass resulting token to the C-b API.

Comment: /identity/ also gives me an error - if you try to access it through browser you get 401 Unauthorized. Same on a local site.

Comment: @Gabriel, discovery (`identity/.well-known/openid-configuration`) and other endpoints should work even if you get `401` while accessing base URL. `https://try.acumatica.com/isv` above exhibits this behavior.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev ok I had somewhat understood what /identity/ was a page we could directly open. My bad :)

Comment: @Gabriel, it's not a page you're supposed to be open directly (although, _maybe_, some links might help), it's supposed to be copy-pasteable to OIDC Discovery-compatible client (e.g [IdentityModel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/)'s `new DiscoveryClient("https://try.acumatica.com/isv/identity/")`), which should add `.well-known/openid-configuration` and use the result.